# Promise then rejected, then resolved

Tags: javascript, promise

We have a chained promise framework type thing set up. It does an async call, a `.then()` which processes the response then resolves or rejects the promise, another component that adds a `.then()` to the promise, and finally this is utilized inside individual components.

This scenario makes no sense to me:

First `then` calls `reject` on the promise.

Second `then` calls its `reject` callback.

Third `then` calls its `resolve` callback.

I would think the third would call its `reject` callback as well. The goal is that if resolve is called all `then`s utilize their individual `resolve` callbacks, if it's rejected each `then` uses its `reject` callback.

```
TheAJAXCall(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        axios({
            //doesn't matter what is here, just pretend it works
        }).then(function(response){
            reject(response)
        });
    });
}

SetupOurCall(){
    return TheAJAXCall().then(function(){
        console.log("second then resolved"); //ignored as expected
        return response;
    }, function(){
        console.log("second then rejected"); //called as expected
    })
}

MyFunction = function(){
    SetupOurCall().then(function(){
        console.log("How did I get resolved");  //this is resolved?!?!?
    }, function(){
        console.log("I want this to be rejected"); //why not rejected?
    })
}
```

Comment: Remove the second callback to the .then from SetupOurCall, then think about what the implications of that fixing it are.

Comment: @KevinB That doesn't fix it... MyFunction is still logging the resolve callback, SetupOurCall doesn't log anything. Another hint maybe?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: The `function(){
        console.log("second then rejected"); //called as expected
    }` does *handle* the exception. The promise returned by `SetupOurCall()` will be resolved with the `then` called callback's return value - `undefined`. To reject that promise, re-`throw` an error from the handler, or return a rejected promise.

Comment: See this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/rsjkn1gb/ you'll note that doThree properly calls reject, but because it has a second .then() callback that doesn't return a rejected promise or an error or throw an error, the final promise is resolved. Omitting the reject handler in doThree would cause the final reject to occur.